# Session conflicts with multiple Laravel projects on one server

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have a shared server for several `Laravel` projects. Example:

```
x.x.x.x/project1
x.x.x.x/project2
```

My problem is that when I try to login in `project1`, `project2` will automatically logout. Is it because of `Laravel` sessions?

Could someone suggest what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of the session cookie is configurable. Take a look at the `path` key in `config/session.php`

Answer (score 3):

This is not a session issue, but a cookie issue.
You can fix `APP_NAME` in your `.env` file differently for each project.

This is because of the cookie configuration part of the session.php file.

```
'cookie' => env(
    'SESSION_COOKIE',
    Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the session cookie identifier to add the environment, so I could have a dev and live site open in the same browser at the same time.  Here is the code I replaced in config/session.php for the cookie:

```
'cookie' => env(
    'SESSION_COOKIE',
    str_slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').env('APP_ENV','dev').'_session'
),
```