# multiple laravel project in the same server session auth conflict

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.3, session-cookies

i have two laravel project in the same server i use auth for all projects. When i login to `project1` and then i login in to `project2` my `project1` will be log out. How  can i login to all project by avoid session conflict??

in my `project1` i keep default `path=>'/'`

i try to change `config/session` in project2 by change `path => '/'` to `path=>'/new'`

but it still not working.. Any solution for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Laravel 5 projects on the same domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37193079/multiple-laravel-5-projects-on-the-same-domain)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647464/session-conflicts-with-multiple-laravel-projects-on-one-server

Comment: @devk when i change path project 2 i can't login

Comment: @Devon also change cookie??

Comment: Yes, as the session path of `/` would still create problems for `/new` just like `/new` would conflict with `/new/deeper`

Comment: @Devon can you show me your answer please

Comment: Are both projects in the same virtual host? (how does that even work?)

Comment: @apokryfos so we should create new virtual host??

Comment: If you have `subdomain1.example.com` and `subdomain2.example.com` there wouldn't be any crossover between sessions/cookies which is what seems to be the problem here.

Comment: @apokryfos i only test it in my local machine  with xampp

Comment: @apokryfos http://localhos/project1/login

Comment: @apokryfos and http://localhost/project2/login

Comment: @apokryfos when i change session path in project2 i can't login

Comment: The problem is if you set the session path in the config, you're setting it for both projects (which is bad). Best idea is to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268205/how-to-create-virtual-host-on-xampp or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-windows

Comment: There's no way around it. If you want to use the exact same code for 2 different sites but still be able to differentiate then there must be a way to differentiate. Absolute worse case would be to "hack" the core `index.php` and set an environment variable based on the current `/path`, but vhost is the suggested way.

Comment: @apokryfos okk i try it thank for your idea

Comment: @apokryfos how can i access to my project from another PC in LAN example: when i type project1.dev it's not working

Comment: @Heshan first of all ensure that you can access that PC by its IP (e.g. 192.168.1.X) and then [modify your hosts file](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) on the other PC to point `project1.dev` to that IP.